# Slow reaction of MouseClick event for NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, .net, events, click, notifyicon

I noticed strange behaviour of left-click event for NotifyIcon.

I have a code like this:

```
private void notifyIcon2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
      {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
      }
}
```

The problem is that upon clicking notifyicon in tray string "Hello" is not shown immediately, it takes about 0.5 seconds (half of a second) to react. That is why I can not add some sort of variable-counter for each click of the icon - it just reacts too slow to catch all clicks and increment my variable.

Is there any solution to the problem? I tried MouseClick, MouseDown, MouseUp and Click events, and all of them have such a slow reaction.

Thank you!

Comment: This might just be a Console isssue. Try opening a MessageBox instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I would like to show some kind of message, for example, message box (Console writing is just for testing) upon 5 clicks on notifyicon, but the point is that when I click 5 times, it is not counting like that, because of this 0.5 seconds reaction (it counts like 2 or 3 times). Of course, I can use some different way to show MessageBox, for example, create some menu, but that behavior of NotifyIcon events seems really strange for me, I just would like to know, what is causing such reaction.

Comment: I don't notice any lag on my NotifyIcon.

Comment: If you click too fast then you'll generate MouseDoubleClick events.  Very hard to see what the point might be.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that is really the cause of my problem, fixed it with implementing DoubleClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is related to this little comment they make [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon) (I know this is not this NotifyIcon).

> Note that the LeftClickCommand fires after a short delay (as opposite to the DoubleClickCommand that fires immediately). This is because there is a time span between a first click and a second click for the OS to consider the mouse action a double-click. The NotifyIcon is smart enough to wait this period in order to make sure the LeftClickCommand is only fired if the user does not click a second time within that period.

I tried it and this delay is present on the Form itself as well. This is just how this event works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just dublicated my event for notifyIcon2_DoubleClick event and now it works just perfect. Thank you for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a handler for the DoubleClick event was not a solution in my case where I wanted only the single click to open the NotifyIcon's popup.

I found the `NoLeftClickDelay` property in the code completion that makes things to work as wanted.

```
TaskbarIcon tbIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("MyNotifyIcon");
tbIcon.NoLeftClickDelay = true;
```